Увеличение изображения без потери качества
Возможно увеличить изображение до любых размеров без потери качества?
Возможно это выполнить при помощи php, быть может приложение есть под linux?

Достаточно отключить интерполяцию, и потери становятся теоретически невозможны

смотря что считать потерей качества, а так же о каких конкретно изображениях идет речь - растровых или векторных
